# Hibernate native query creation returns empty result

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this method in my DAO class:

```
public List<Protocolo> buscarProtocolos(int situacao){

    List<Protocolo> protocolos = null;
    protocolosPorSitucao = null;
    String sql = "select * from hibernatedb.protocolo where situacao_id = ?";

    em = HibernateManager.getEntityManager();
    protocolosPorSitucao = em.createNativeQuery(sql, Protocolo.class);
    protocolosPorSitucao.setParameter(1, situacao);

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    logger.info("Buscando protocolos por situacao : "+ situacao);
    protocolos = (List<Protocolo>) protocolosPorSitucao.getResultList();
    logger.info("Protocolos encontrados: "+protocolos.size());
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();

    return protocolos;
}
```

This query `select * from hibernatedb.protocolo where situacao_id = 1` returns one row when executed in pgAdmin3, but hibernate returns 0 rows. Here's the log generated from hibernate:

```
Hibernate: select * from hibernatedb.protocolo where situacao_id = ?
0
```

It means that hibernate returned 0 results, cause my list is empty.

Where's the error in this code?

P.S.: when creating NativeQueries i need to set the database too. That's because a NativeQuery ignores the configs established on the `persistence.xml`?

Comment: have you tried using `:situacaoId` instead of `?` (and then calling `setParameter(situacaoId,1)`. Also I think you should use 1L but I'm not sure how you declare your id in db.

Comment: If I change from ? to :stiaucaoId it returns an error: `Parameter with that position [1] did not exist`

Comment: Have you call it with that `protocolosPorSitucao.setParameter("situacaoId", 1)` (or 1L). Also declare protocolosPorSitucao as `Query protocolosPorSitucao`.

Comment: Now I did this: `String sql = "select * from hibernatedb.protocolo where situacao_id = :situacao_id";` and  `protocolosPorSitucao.setParameter("situacao_id", 1L);` and it doesnt give me any errors, but still no results.

Comment: Solved my problem. I've changed the persistence.xml before to test compatibility with Oracle database and forgot to change it back to my postgresql database, wich has all the data.